# Array check with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, for-loop

1.hey guys,how do i separate these?
2.sorry im newb in this,but been cracking my head for a while,how to make this code write sentences separetly without writing them non stop?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var x=[15,22,28,30,25,11,12,29,27,26];//right numbers
      var c=1;
      var e=0;
      var i=0;
      for (c=1;c<=10;c++) {
        var y=Number(prompt("enter number from 10 to 30",0));
        for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {
          if(y==x[i]) {//checking every number in array
            document.write("u right.<br>");
            e=e+1;
          }
          else {
            document.write("u wrong.<br>");//this writes every time it goes trough the loop,i tried breaking,but it just quits the loop on first number in array,i tried continue,no luck
          }
        }
      }
         if(e<5) {//amount of time you guessed right
          document.write("u lose ");
        }
        else {
          document.write("u win");
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just write why you downvote

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify your question a bit, i.e. what exactly are you trying to achieve and what doesn't work as expected. This will make it more likely to get useful and concrete answers you are probably looking for.

Comment: **im trying to make the program check the array box every time i chose number in prompt,this is training exercise I can write whole column of separate 'if's' ,but chose to make it more prettier and also more trickier for me,main problem is that the loop generates excessive lines of answer,every negative check is displayed,also I dont know how to quit loop properly if answer is right**

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var x=[15,22,28,30,25,11,12,29,27,26];//right numbers
        var c=1;
        var e=0;
        var i=0;
        for (c=1;c<=10;c++)
        {
        var y=Number(prompt("enter number from 10 to 30",0));
        var right = false;
        for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
          {
            if(y==x[i]) //checking every number in array
           {
             right = true;
           }
          }
          if (right)
           {
             e++;
             document.write("u right.<br>");
           }
           else {
                document.write("u wrong.<br>");
           }
         }
       if(e<5)//amount of time you guessed right
       {
       document.write("u lose ");
       }
      else
      {document.write("u win");}



     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Your code can be optimized in many areas:

```
    <html>
  <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var x=[15,22,28,30,25,11,12,29,27,26];//right numbers
          var c=1;
          var e=0;
          var c=0;
          while (c < 10) 
          {
            c++;
            var y=Number(prompt("enter number from 10 to 30",0));
            if (x.indexOf(y) != -1)
            {
              e++;
              document.write("u right.<br>");
            }
            else {
              document.write("u wrong.<br>");
            }
          }
          if(e<5)//amount of time you guessed right
          {
            document.write("u lose ");
          }
          else
          {
            document.write("u win");
          }
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah we didnt learn how to use true or false,this helps alot:) I still dont understand this,but I will try
and your code is working,amazing thanx!

Comment: if i understand right,in your second edit you use x.indexOf(y)! to search it in array from zero? thats what -1 stands for?

Comment: indexOf returns -1 if array does not contains the parameter "!= is not equal" say when you do find a resemblance (is true).

Comment: so it searches all the arrays indexes in one step? ,it sure doesnt write 10 times that im right or wrong,so thats a win

Comment: Yes indexOf is looking inside all array indexes https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: your welcome mate, still I'm close to Russia but I'm not russian, good lock with programming, and mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf method of array for checking whether value is available in array or not.

If value is not available then return -1 else return position of that value.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var x = [15,22,28,30,25,11,12,29,27,26];
      var e = 0;
      for (var c=1;c<=10;c++) {
        var y = Number(prompt("enter number from 10 to 30",0));        
        x.indexOf(y) > 0?(document.write("u right.<br>"),e++):document.write("u r wrong.<br>");
      }
      e<5?document.write("u lose "):document.write("u win");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks ,but what is this question mark after indexof,is it like "if"?
Im quite frankly very impressed by this indexof function,but still we are not using it at this moment in school,we only use for,while,case,if,else if and switch

Comment: for more information please visit http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp